# Should I use a colon or a semicolon in the following sentence?

Tags: punctuation

> Unlike the fictional character, Gaby didn't control gravity:/;
>   gravity controlled her.

Should it be a colon or a semicolon? Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a choice between a colon and em dash, not a semicolon.

A **colon** can be used between independent clauses when the second explains or illustrates the first.

An **em dash** can be used when you want to emphasize the conclusion of your sentence.

Check out this excellent punctuation guide for [Colon](http://www.thepunctuationguide.com/colon.html) and [Em dash](http://www.thepunctuationguide.com/em-dash.html).
As for why you should not use a semicolon, none of the uses for a [Semicolon](http://www.thepunctuationguide.com/semicolon.html) fits your requirement.